# Read from console data previously "System.out.println()" possible? [JAVA]

Tags: java, eclipse, console, java.util.scanner

This is not the basic Scanner(System.in).

I have some recursive methods that I saw online that does exactly what I want but now I need to count the number of lines that have been "outputed" to the console.

So, I run the program. It does some computations and then it writes on the console some lines (as you can see above) and I need to , in the end on the computations (after the execution of the main), count the number of that lines and write it to somewhere.

Example of the output:

[image]
Does anyone know how it can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you add the output to a buffer when it is writing to std output?

Comment: If you have access to the code that is doing the output, why not insert a counter in there?

Comment: Thanks u both. As I said it is recursive code. I've already tried what @Neijwiert said but it does not go well..

Comment: @Tito Then show us what you've attempted. It should be possible.

Comment: @Neijwiert ok. I've already deleted it but let me see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the class [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) from Apache Common IO that split the outputs into two streams. This way you can still publish your stream in the default output and log them in a file. With the outputs in the file you can do whatever you wanted (count lines...).

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you declare a variable `counter` and initialize it with 0. After every `System.out.println()` statement, you increment the counter by adding `counter++`.
As final Statement in your main-Method, you print the variable to the console:

```
System.out.println("Counter: "+counter");
```

If that doesn´t work for you, you could still write the output of the program to a file instead of the console, read that file afterwards and look for line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've already tried the counter aproach but as it's recursive it doesn't go wel.. And I've already tried to write into a file aswell..

Comment: I don´t know why a recursive program should prevent the counter approach, but as I don´t know your code, I can´t really answer that.
Writing the output to a file should definetly work though, what was your problem with that approach?

Comment: It does not. The problem is that I loose control of the flow of the code and I don't know where to put the counter. I'll put the code in the question. It's smal..